# JAVA Swing client, Data Access to Remote Database; Ibatis

Tags: java, jboss, data-access-layer, ibatis, data-access

I've got a Java client that needs to access a remote database. It is the goal to hide database credentials from the user and not hardcode any credentials within the code. Therefore, the database access will probably have to be on the server side.

I'm restricted to use Ibatis as a data abstraction framework. Apart from that I have JBoss running on the webserver, allowing me to use data sources.

How would you design the remote database access and data serialization/deserialization. would you prefer web services of some kind of data stream over a socket? How would you realize either of both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a Service Layer and expose it over RMI - possibly as EJB3 stateless session beans as you have JBoss, possibly as pure RMI. I wouldn't bother with web services unless you have a specific need. RMI will take case of serialisation for you.

Your service layer needs to expose a method to authenticate users using their credentials entered on startup of the Swing app. All calls for data go through the service layer. No SQL exists in the Swing app.

There are other benfits of this arrangment other than just hiding the database credentials. Not only do you end up with a layered architecture, but you gain efficiencies from sharing prepared statements amongst all your clients by having a single data source on the server.

Answer (score 0):

So you want users to be able to access the database without knowing the credentials? Your only option is server-side database access. Unfortunately there is no way of hiding the username and password in Java -- if you put it into a properties file and encrypt it, a determined attacker could still attach a debugger and see what values are being held in your code.

Also, unless you're connecting to the DB over a secure connection someone could run a packet sniffer such as tcpdump and get the credentials there.

You say that you're running a JBoss server, what might be best is to set up remote EJBs so that your client application doesn't access the database directly - it has to go via your EJB methods. (It doesn't have to be EJB, by the way, you could do something such as web services if you prefer).

The point is, your server talks to the databas directly, and your client's only access is via a limited set of interfaces you define on the server.

Answer (score 0):

As has been already said, you have to connect to a server which handles the database connection.  There is no way to effectively prevent someone from breaking your security, with 30 minutes of effort.

If the clients are connecting somewhat locally, within an intranet, using EJB's on your appserver is probably the best choice... though you probably want stateless session beans, i wouldnt necessarily discount message driven beans.

For longer distances where the traffic is coming from the outside, I would use webservices over HTTPS

In any event, most appservers have mechanisms to expose their EJB's as webservices, with the WSDL; and there are about a hundred utilities to generate clients, to call the webservice, from a WSDL (axis's wsdl2java works well enough)